# recurrent zfs read and write errors while smart tests are ok

Tags: smart, zfs

I'm using OpenZFS 2.1.5 on Ubuntu 22.04.

`zpool status -v` show **recurrent** read and write errors on one of my mechanical drives. However, SMART test doesn't show any problem with the disk. By recurrent I mean that the errors have been continuously increasing for several days even after having performed multiple scrubs.

After performing a long test, `smartctl -a /dev/sdi` gives the following output:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-71-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate IronWolf
Device Model:     ST8000VN004-2M2101
Serial Number:    WSD5CNQY
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0e395c73b
Firmware Version: SC60
User Capacity:    8,001,563,222,016 bytes [8.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat May 20 09:41:56 2023 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  559) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 710) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x50bd) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   081   064   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       115024985
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   078   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   048   048   020    Old_age   Always       -       53805
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   085   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       284588125
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       6371
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   048   048   020    Old_age   Always       -       54171
 18 Head_Health             0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   065   039   040    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 35 (0 54 35 34 0)
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       53631
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   069   069   000    Old_age   Always       -       63782
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   035   061   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (0 19 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   081   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       115024985
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2936 (169 98 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       15091623608
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       199570567296

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      6283         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Here the a zfs event corresponding to one of this error:

```
May 20 2023 08:43:08.675217723 ereport.fs.zfs.io
        class = "ereport.fs.zfs.io"
        ena = 0x4e2f19a0af71fc01
        detector = (embedded nvlist)
                version = 0x0
                scheme = "zfs"
                pool = 0x22e98240f9179f3d
                vdev = 0xdc247207eae1c346
        (end detector)
        pool = "zpanier"
        pool_guid = 0x22e98240f9179f3d
        pool_state = 0x0
        pool_context = 0x0
        pool_failmode = "wait"
        vdev_guid = 0xdc247207eae1c346
        vdev_type = "disk"
        vdev_path = "/dev/sdi1"
        vdev_ashift = 0x9
        vdev_complete_ts = 0x454e2f190abaf
        vdev_delta_ts = 0xf22e2
        vdev_read_errors = 0x43
        vdev_write_errors = 0x2
        vdev_cksum_errors = 0x0
        vdev_delays = 0x0
        parent_guid = 0xd9ce168f4fdd4616
        parent_type = "raidz"
        vdev_spare_paths = 
        vdev_spare_guids = 
        zio_err = 0x5
        zio_flags = 0x180880
        zio_stage = 0x1000000
        zio_pipeline = 0x1080000
        zio_delay = 0x334ef7959
        zio_timestamp = 0x454dfb70bd179
        zio_delta = 0x334ef8ae4
        zio_priority = 0x0
        zio_offset = 0x516e48e8000
        zio_size = 0x1000
        zio_objset = 0x490
        zio_object = 0x41310c0
        zio_level = 0x0
        zio_blkid = 0x1
        time = 0x6468881c 0x283f013b 
        eid = 0x8922ee
```

This pool has been working without issue for more than a year and half.

Should I assume that error reported by zfs indicate a problem with the disk that is not yet reflected by the SMART data? Should I change the disk right away?

Comment: Include SMART report, disk model etc.. I mean if this is a spinner a bump against the desk may cause some temp issue that got logged without being a real issue, SSD's don't care about this. This is just example. Please add additional info to topic, not in comment.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Thanks for your advice. By SMART report, do you mean the output of `smartctl -a`?

Comment: I don't spot obvious errors there. Note that 'bad smart' = bad, 'good smart =/= good. IOW smart not showing issues does not automatically lead to conclusion that all is well. Is it an idea to add the actual relevant log parts for those of us who are more intimate with ZFS?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Thanks, I added an extract from `zpool event -v` output.

Comment: I am not expert on the matter but this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399649 seems to suggest you can dig a little deeper and get some idea about the actual errors it ran into.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it seems that the issue came from my SAS cable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Amazing, the corresponding SMART attribute (UDMA_CRC_Error_Count) seems oblivious. Consider accepting your own answer so others can see it's resolved.

Comment: are you going to accept your own answer @colibrisson ?  it would be nice if you can explain how you determined it was the cabling.  Did the errors just disappear after you shut down,  (or exported) and replaced cabling?  Was it a Mini-SAS 8087, x4 sata or sas cable?  did you replace both of them?